# Excel 2016 How to avg D HH:MM

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've exported data from a query and the format for the data is D HH:MM and I need to find the average.  I can't figure out the conversion.

For Example....

```
3 00:19
2 01:44
1 03:39
7 09:18
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to convert if the data is numeric and formatted to show as `D HH:MM`. So just average the cells and format with the same format.

If the data is not numeric, but text, i.e. if there is a space character between the day and the time, then you can use this formula to generate the respective date/time value

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)+TIME(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,2),RIGHT(A1,2),0)
```

Put that formula into a helper column, then average the helper column and format the result with custom format `D HH:MM`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
{=AVERAGE(TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B4," ",":")))}
```

It IS an array formula, but carries none of the usual baggage since you surely want it in a single cell.

`SUBSTITUTE()` puts it in a form Excel will recognize as time, if you wish (just that function returns a text result).

`TIMEVALUE()` converts the result to a numerical time value in Excel's system.

`AVERAGE()` finds exactly that.

Must be entered as a CSE array, or it results in an error.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you change the query to use just convert these values into hour values.
Then you can use a ranged average on the hours.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2houk.png)